# How to find the total volume of a stock, and then calculate the yearly / % change. How do i do this across three sheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to write a VBA code to find the sum of a stocks volume, and return that in column L. Then i need to find the yearly change in stock price, and calculate the percentage change from that, and return that in column J. I need to do this across three sheets.

So far I've tried doing this for one sheet

Here is my current code for one sheet. Right now it is returning the last recorded volume of the stock, and then the next row is adding the subsequent stocks last recorded volume to the previous stocks volume and putting that.

```vba
Sub multiple_year_stock_data()
    'Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Double
    Dim i As Long
    Dim total_volume As Double
    total_volume = 0
    
    'Extract stock data (ticker symbol, opening price, closing price, volume)
    Dim ticker As String
    Dim openPrice As Double
    Dim closePrice As Double
    Dim volume As Double
    Dim yeardate As Double
    Dim Stock_info As Double
   Stock_info = 2
    ' Set the worksheet containing the stock data
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        'Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2018")
        ' Find the last row with data in column A
        lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        ' Loop through the rows to extract stock data
        For i = 2 To lastRow ' Assuming data starts from row 2
            'create loop to cycle through tickers and then create function to select the close value for the last ticker
            'ticker = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value ' Assuming ticker symbol is in column A
            '  openPrice = ws.Cells(i, 3).Value ' Assuming opening price is in column B
            ' closePrice = ws.Cells(i, 6).Value ' Assuming closing price is in column C
            'volume = ws.Cells(i, 7).Value ' Assuming volume is in column G
            'yeardate = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value ' DAte is in column 2
            If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value <> ws.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value Then
                ticker = Cells(i, 1).Value
                ws.Cells(Stock_info, "I") = ticker
                'Add to the volume total
                  total_volume = total_volume + ws.Cells(i, 7).Value
                'Print ticker symbol in ticker column
                ' Range("I" & Stock_info).Value = ticker
                'Print Volume in volume column
                'Range("j" & Stock_info).Value = total_volume
                'Reset volume total
                volume_total = 0
                'print total f
                ws.Cells(Stock_info, "L").Value = total_volume

                'Else
                '   volume_total = Cells(i, 7).Value
                Stock_info = Stock_info + 1
                    
                Else
                ws.Cells(Stock_info, "L") = total_volume
            End If
        Next i
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Expected outcome

[image: Expected outcome]

my outcome

[image: my outcome]

setup with tickers (I've coded in tickers)

[image: setup with tickers (I've coded in tickers)]

Comment: I've added two photos, one of the e expected outcome and one of mine

Comment: It would be useful to see the headers so we know which column is column `J` and which one is column `L`. Also what are you starting with?

Comment: new pitcure has the setup

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Please create MD table with online tool [Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). What's the logic to calculate the last 3 cols?

Answer (score 0):

This code returns the intended result in my worksheets.

```
Sub multiple_year_stock_data()
    'Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Double
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i, j, Total As Long
    Dim startprice, endprice As Double

    'Extract stock data (ticker symbol, opening price, closing price, 
    'volume)
    Dim ticker As String


   j = 2
    ' Set the worksheet containing the stock data
    For Each ws In Worksheets
     ws.Range("I2:L1048576").Clear
        lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        ' Loop through the rows to extract stock data
        ticker = Cells(2, 1).Value
        For i = 2 To lastRow ' Assuming data starts from row 2

        
            If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = ws.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value Then
                If startprice = 0 Then
                 startprice = ws.Cells(i, 3).Value
                Else
                End If
            
                Total = Total + ws.Cells(i, 7).Value
            
           Else
               If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value <> ws.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then
                endprice = ws.Cells(i, 6).Value
                startprice = ws.Cells(i, 3).Value
               Else
                endprice = ws.Cells(i, 6).Value
               End If
                ws.Cells(j, 11).Value = (endprice / startprice) - 1
                ws.Cells(j, 11).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
                ws.Cells(j, 10).Value = endprice - startprice
                Total = Total + ws.Cells(i, 7).Value
                ws.Cells(j, 9).Value = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
                ws.Cells(j, 12).Value = Total
                j = j + 1
                Total = 0
                endprice = 0
                startprice = 0
           End If
        Next i
        j = 2
    Next ws
End Sub
```